# How to decrease the size of docker image with gRPC in golang supported?

Tags: docker, go, grpc

I have some server and clients who are communicating using gRPC/golang. Now I want to containerize my application but the size of the docker image containing goland execution and grpc support is larger(more than 1GB). I would like to decrease the size of the docker image.

The required golang version is 1.9 and higher. Here is the Dockerfile script is given. If there is other way please suggest it.

```
FROM golang:1.11

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install git unzip build-essential autoconf libtool

RUN git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git && \
    cd protobuf && \
    ./autogen.sh && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig && \
    make clean && \
    cd .. && \
    rm -r protobuf

RUN go get google.golang.org/grpc

RUN go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go

RUN ls -la

WORKDIR /helloworld

COPY . /helloworld

RUN protoc -I helloworld/ helloworld/helloworld.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:helloworld

CMD ["go", "run", "helloworld/greeter_server/main.go"]
```

Comment: What the content of current directroy? Did you try to use `stage` build? Did you use the `.dockerignore` ?

Comment: Current directory is grpc example which is available at grpc repository [ https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples ]. I don't know about stage built. can you provide resources for it?

Comment: You need to exclude from context things you dont need, you can do it by `COPY` only needed directroy or using `.dockerignore` file. Here is some info about mutli stage build https://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/

Comment: Can you share from which image you start? the `FROM` in the `Dockerfile`

Comment: @Matteo Currently I am starting from golang 1.11 but I have seen it starting from debian and they may be small in size but I don't know much about it.

Comment: Build the binary and copy it to another image? using Multi-stage builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to make a multistage docker image like this

```
# Compile stage
FROM golang:1.11 as build-env

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install git unzip build-essential autoconf libtool

RUN git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git && \
    cd protobuf && \
    ./autogen.sh && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig && \
    make clean && \
    cd .. && \
    rm -r protobuf

RUN go get google.golang.org/grpc

RUN go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go

RUN ls -la

WORKDIR /helloworld

COPY . /helloworld

RUN protoc -I helloworld/ helloworld/helloworld.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:helloworld
RUN go build -o server helloworld/greeter_server/main.go

# Making image
FROM alpine:3.8 AS host
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        ca-certificates
COPY --from=build-env /helloworld/server /
# copy any other files you need

WORKDIR /
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["server"]
```

Comment: you're following this article on a Linux machine, simply replace alpine:3.8 with debian:linux, and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) base images and multi-stage builds. That might help you.